# 3 days worth of RR interval in movesense DataLogger

Tags: movesense

Is it possible to store 3 days worth of RR interval (From Meas/HR) information using the Movesense DataLogger? I have it running at the moment, but it only seems to store about 5 hours worth of data.

If there is another way of storing RR interval that uses less memory that I am not aware of please do let me know as well...

I am have the "plain_app" firmware running on the movesense (so it does not power off after Bluetooth disconnects) and the DataLoggerSample android app running on my phone.

Thanks,
Helic

Answer (score 0):

The data storage has 384kB of space. The DataLogger/Logbook uses about 6% for different kind of overhead so the rest is available for stored data. If you are storing /Meas/HR then the generated storage format is total of 6 bytes long. That means that there is about 61000 RR intervals of storage space. Depending on heart rate (there is one update per RR detection in /Meas/HR) the storage should last between 5.5-17 hours (HR: 180/60). Since the storage format is autogenerated from the service description, it is possible to optimize the format by making the kind of service interface that suits your needs and using that as the path in DataLogger/Config.

So to get to the required 3 days of storage, I'd create a "proxy service" that subscribes /Meas/HR (or /Algo/ECGRR if you use our Pan-Tompkins SW implementation) and changes the format to something more suitable. This will require implementing your own firmware though.

Some simple ideas how to make the storage last longer in your use case:

1. Just have RR as uint16 (ms). This means storage per RR is 2 bytes instead of 6 and should triple your storage space. Easy to implement and should triple the storage time, which does not get you to 3 days but improves the situation a lot and does not need anything special in mobile side when interpreting the data.
2. Another way is to combine multiple measurements on the sensor and store them in a larger block in a compressed format. For example have a RAM buffer that collects 512 RR samples and then runs some block compression on it. The format of the service would then consist of databytes of the compressed format. Disadvantage is the need of unpacking code when interpreting the data in the mobile app.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarification. I am interested in your suggestion #1: RR as uint16(ms). Is it possible to configure that without changing the firmware. i.e. via the mobile software? Either way, can you point me to some sample code to help me understand what is required so that I can build it? Thanks a lot! Helic

Comment: You'll need to do your own firmware, it is not possible from the mobile.