# What is the definition of the notification response for Movesense /Algo/ECGRR?

Tags: movesense, heartrate

What is the content & format of the notification response for `/Algo/ECGRR`?

I've subscribed to it on the movesense hardware using a slightly modified version of the [DataLoggerSample Android app](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src/master/android/samples/DataLoggerSample/app/src/main/java/com/movesense/samples/dataloggersample/DataLoggerActivity.java) from the [Movesense-mobile-lib repository](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib), with the sensor running the default device firmware. I'm able to pull a `.json` log off the sensor after a while.

(This was mentioned in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969515) I ran across while trying to figure out how to log data on the device.)

But I don't see the default device firmware in the [Movesense-device-lib repository](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib), and there are no `/Algo` APIs listed in [the online docs](http://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/api_reference/).

I'm looking for the specific units and internal representations of the notification response. The units would normally be given in the `yaml` API definition, for example, here it is for `/Meas/HR`:

```
  /Meas/HR/Subscription:
post:
  description: |
    Combined subscription to average HR and R-R data.
  responses:
    200:
      description: Operation completed successfully
      schema:
        $ref: 'types.yaml#/definitions/HRData'
    x-notification:
      description: |
        Notifications comprise average HR (Hz) with the latest RR (ms) data
      schema:
        $ref: 'types.yaml#/definitions/HRData'
```

and the `post/x-notification/description` field tells us the units.

From the `.json` output with norification responses for `/Algo/ECGRR`, e.g.:

```
{"Algo":[
  {"RR":742,"SNR":16,"Timestamp":14326776},
  {"RR":743,"SNR":16,"Timestamp":14327521},
  {"RR":726,"SNR":17,"Timestamp":14328240},
  {"RR":720,"SNR":14,"Timestamp":14328961},
  ...
  {"RR":660,"SNR":12,"Timestamp":20613697}]
```

We can *assume* the units are:

1. milliseconds for RR interval
2. unitless for SNR
3. milliseconds for Timestamp

and we can make an educated guess that the internal representations are:

1. uint16 for RR interval
2. uint8 for SNR
3. uint32 for Timestamp

but I'd rather see confirmation somewhere, instead of *assuming*.

And what zero reference is the Timestamp field relative to?

The [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969515/3-days-worth-of-rr-interval-in-movesense-datalogger) tells us

> If you are storing /Meas/HR then the generated storage format is total
>   of 6 bytes long.

and the `.json` output is a float with an integer:

```
"Meas":{"HR":[
  {"average":98.791664123535156,"rrData":[720]},
  {"average":97.158706665039062,"rrData":[712]},
  ...
```

so an educated guess would be the internal representation is `float32` & `uint16`, but that's still just a guess.

How long is the storage format for `/Algo/ECGRR`? and where do I find that information for other types? since I don't see it in the API.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: SO is where the movesense team directs you in the [README for movesense-device-lib](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/README.md) -- where else would you suggest I ask the question?

Comment: I wouldn't know but, even then, that would be recommending an off-site resource and it's not allowed here. I suggest you ask that movesense team. Please delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED to answer modified question**

You're correct about the structure of the /Algo/ECGRR notification. I've attached the definition from yaml file below for you:

```
definitions:
  ECGRRData:
    required:
      - Timestamp
      - RR
      - SNR
    properties:
      Timestamp:
        description: Local timestamp of RR detection.
        type: integer
        format: uint32
        x-unit: millisecond
      RR:
        description: RR interval
        type: integer
        format: uint16
        x-unit: millisecond
      SNR:
        description: Estimated SNR of ECG signal (dB)
        type: integer
        format: int8
```

---

**Original answer**

The question could be better rephrased as "How can I include /Algo/ECGRR service for my own firmware?" and our current documentation does not contain that info too well (it will be added).

**Short answer**: The ECGRR service is a *separately licensed* software module that is available to the developers that need it. The way to get it is to request it from the Movesense team (info (at) movesense.com) and it may incur licensing fees when ordering production quantities (decided by the people in charge of pricing).

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on ECGRR being a separately licensed module.

I've rephrased the question to ask specifically for the units and internal representation. Including information like that in the API yaml would be helpful for people like me, getting started tinkering with the movesense device.